# How to tell if a WiFi adapter supports WiDi/Miracast?

Tags: wireless-networking, miracast

I'm looking to purchase an (USB) adapter for WiDi/Miracast use.  How can I (before purchase) determine if a WiFi adapter supports wireless display/Miracast?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: but this is a driver question as well ..

Comment: You could probably download the driver and investigate which NDIS version it uses. Miracast requires at least NDIS 6.3 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking all over the place for a USB WIFI adapter that supports WiDi / Miracast. I suspect that many or most of the newer models support it, but I haven't been able to find confirmation on any of them until now. I just found [this post on the TP-Link forum](https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/243624) from 2020-12-29 which gives a list of adapters that support Miracast. Hopefully someone else will find this helpful! Here's the list:

> - Archer T2U Nano
> - Archer T2U Plus
> - Archer T2U v3.0
> - Archer T9UH
> - Archer T4UHP
> - Archer T4U
> - Archer T4UH
> - TL-WN823N v3.0
> - Archer TX3000E
> - Archer TX50E

Answer (score 0):

WiDi support related to graphical card support, not Wi-Fi adapter.

Miracast has also nothing to do with CPU, it's a feature in modern wireless WiFi Direct network adapters (list of WLAN adapters supporting Miracast).

Additionally, the display adapter must support Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) (almost all modern display drivers support it).

Comment: This answer isn’t accurate.  Miracast requires both the display driver and a compatible wireless adapter.  Nvidia and AMD display drivers currently do not support Miracast.

Comment: Also note that for some wireless adapters, you would need to install, e.g., Realtek's rather than Intel's driver for particular models in order to have the Miracast feature working, as Intel stopped supporting it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to send out your screen image over WIDI, you don't want a WIFI dongle, instead there are WIDI dongles which attach to your HDMI output and get power over a USB cord. Have a look at the Microsoft Wireless Display adapter for an example. At the least you're looking at around $30 for a generic Miracast dongle, but a WIFI dongle alone won't get the video signal to transmit it to a remote display.

Certain laptop motherboards (usually ones which are built with a mostly-Intel chipset) have internal WIDI since they can route the video from the internal video to the WIDI chips, but these are kind of rare.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought it would be sufficient just to have a compatible wifi card (my laptop have a wrong one, but has the rest of the specs)

Comment: could you give some product links please?

Comment: Search for 'WIDI adapter' on ebay or Amazon and you'll see a whole slew of them.